# React native navigate to another class

Tags: reactjs, react-native, navigation

Hi I'm usign react native with stacknavigator heres my code

```
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import {Main} from "./Main";
import {Detail} from "./Detail";
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

function App() {
       return (
      <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Main">
        <Stack.Screen name="Main" component={Main} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Detail" component={Detail} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>     
    )  
}
export default App;
```

Works fine on main page. I want to navigate to detail page with props data .

Mainpage.

```
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native'; 
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';



    export  class Main  extends Component {
    
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
          this.state = {
            dataSource: [],
            
      
          };
        }
```

....

```
<Button
        title="Go to Details"
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Detail')}
```

When I press the button it says

[image]

Also tryed this but it gives another error.

[image]

How can i navigate it. Thank you

```
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';

function Main  () {
  const navigation = useNavigation();
          />
```

NEW

I changed the nav code now it navigates

```
<Button
        title="Go to Details"
        onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Details',{list:this.state.dataSource})  }
      />
```

In Details screen
I gotta set state the data comes from props. Just this part

```
const { yourParam } = this.props;

export  class Details extends Component {

    constructor() {
      super();
      this.state = {
        dataSource: [],
      
  
      };
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the `useNavigation()` (and you can't use a hook in a class component) You have to use the navigation prop.

```js
this.props.navigation.navigate('Detail')
```

You can add params to the navigate function.

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('Detail', { yourParam: someData });
```

and on your `Detail` component, you will be able to get the params.

```js
const Detail = ({ route }) => {
   const { yourParam } = route.params;

   console.log(yourParam);

   return (
     <View />
   );
}
```

Class:

```js
const { yourParam } = this.props;

export  class Details extends Component {

    constructor() {
      super();
      this.state = {
        dataSource: [],
      
  
      };
    }
    componentDidMount() {
       console.log(this.props.route.params)
    }
   render() {
     return (<View />) 
   }
}
```

Comment: Well yeah this type works fine but Also how can i pass data with navitagion to Detail page. In main I declared as  this.state = {
            dataSource: [], So how to pass it to detail page. Thank you

Comment: I couldn't make it can you check my edited question

Comment: I think you really need to check before all how OOP works actually. You cannot use ˋthis` outside a class. Console log your this.props.route.params in the constructor and you will see all your route params.

Comment: Yes I accually now 'this' works in class but when i put this this.props line in class it says can't declare const inside here. Just gotta get props data and set it to state

Comment: You need to deal with the component lifecycle. try to console log this.props when the component is mounted. Check the edited response.

Comment: Yes with this type i cna pass data and route. Thank you have a good day